# blade seems not work

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

It directly show `@csrf` & `@method('PUT')` on the page

> You may use the `@method` Blade directive to generate the `_method` input:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    @method('PUT')
</form>
```

These code does not work.

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? Is it 5.6?

Comment: This directives will be added in laravel 5.6 and are not available in earlier versions of the framework.

Comment: Define `These code does not work.`. Do you have any errors? Does it just not show? Do any other directives work? `@if(1==1) <h1>Yeah</h1> @endif` for example

Comment: No error.my version is 5.6. It just show the @csrf on the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These directives are coming in Laravel 5.6 as it was mentioned by [Laravel News](https://laravel-news.com/new-blade-directives-laravel-5-6).

As I am writing this answer, Laravel 5.6 have not yet been released.

You can do this to install a fresh version of Laravel 5.6:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project-name-here dev-develop
```